# How to scroll a div even if it's not hovered

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I have a fixed div with 40% width of the window width, that can be scrolled, but only if you hover on it. Is there a way to make it scrollable even if I'm not hovering it?

Will [mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) help me in this situation?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ekcbpvr/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fullwidth"></div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fullwidth{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.gallery{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: You will have to show some code to get some help.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the contents of the div programmatically?  Please give a few more specifics, as well as both your applicable HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I added the code. The red squares are only scrollable when I hover on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.scrollTop` and `.scrollLeft`

```
$('.myDiv').animate({scrollTop: 200 }, 1000);
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/n9f3d0oa/

Comment: I'll try this, will report with results :)

Comment: Tried this, but nothing happened. Is it because I have `overfrlow-y: scroll`?

Comment: If you check my edit, I updated the units, `20px` no, is `20`, try that

Comment: Nope, still nothing I'm afraid. I'll look into scrollTop a bit.